# How is it possible that my if statement does not do what i want?

Tags: if-statement

rock = '''
_______
---'   ****)
(*****)
(*****)
(****)
---.**(**_)
'''

paper = '''
_______
---'   ****)****
______)
____***)
*******)
---.**********)
'''

scissors = '''
_______
---'   ****)****
______)
_*********)
(****)
---.**(***)
'''

#Write your code below this line 
import random
choices = [rock, paper, scissors]
user_choice = input("What do you choose? Type 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper or 2 for Scissors.\n")
if user_choice == "0":
print(rock)
elif user_choice == "1":
print(paper)
else:
print(scissors)

computer_choice = random.randint(0, 2)
print(computer_choice)
print(choices[computer_choice])

if(user_choice == "0" and computer_choice == "2"):
print("You win.")

I initially thought that I messed up with having multiple if statements, but that cannot be the problem because I deleted all of them and left only one if statement. I waited for the if statement to come true by clicking Run over and over again till the condition came true but nothing happened. It should have said that I won. This is a practice exercise for a Udemy course but I am desperate here. I tried everything but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put quotation marks in the print code
also you should remove the quotation marks in the if statement

Comment: You mean the very last print? I tried removing quotes in the if statement and it does nothing for me.

Comment: when the user types a number, it gets saved as a number not a character. therefore you don't need to put quotation marks around the numbers--> user_choice == 0

Comment: also if user_choice == 0: 
    print("rock") 
elif user_choice == 1:
    print("paper") 
else: print("scissors")

Comment: Ok, thanks, I deleted the quotes around numbers but it didn't solve my problem. The problem is that even when I win, it doesn't print "You win". And the quotes around paper, rock, scissors should not be there I believe, because I do not want it print as a string. There is ASCII art saved into those variables and I want to print that. But I messed up the code when posting so I am sorry.

Comment: I posted a code that works for you.

Comment: Thank you, I finally figured it out. Your if statements really helped and I see where was the problem now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Perhaps you can insert code with some comments to demonstrate your suggestion. In general this proves to be helpful to other readers when they stumble upon your answer.

Answer (score 0):

here's a code that works:

```
import random
user_action = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")
possible_actions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

computer_action = random.choice(possible_actions)
print(f"\nYou chose {user_action}, computer chose {computer_action}.\n")
if user_action == computer_action:
    print(f"Both players selected {user_action}. It's a tie!")
elif user_action == "rock":
    if computer_action == "scissors":
        print("Rock smashes scissors! You win!")
    else:
        print("Paper covers rock! You lose.")
elif user_action == "paper":
    if computer_action == "rock":
        print("Paper covers rock! You win!")
    else:
        print("Scissors cuts paper! You lose.")
elif user_action == "scissors":
    if computer_action == "paper":
        print("Scissors cuts paper! You win!")
    else:
        print("Rock smashes scissors! You lose.")
```